# Как повернуть префаб в Unity c помощью кода

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d, prefabs

Я пишу  игру на Unity и я добавил возможность бросать трезубец но мне нужно что-бы когда я поворачивался влево или в право prefab трезубца тоже повернулся, создался и полетел.

Вот мой код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _rb;
    public GameObject tridentPrefab;
    public Transform throwingPoint;
    public Animator animator;
    public Transform attackPoint;
    public LayerMask enemyLayer;
    private bool flipRight = true;
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public float speed = 150f;
    public float attackRange = 0.5f;
    public int damage = 50;
    public float throwForce = 10f;
    



    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //_rb.velocity = new Vector2(h * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, _rb.velocity.y);
        _rb.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector2(h * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, _rb.velocity.y));
        animator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(h));


         if (h < 0 && flipRight)
         {
            Flip();
            //tridentPrefab.transform.rotation = (0f, 0f, 90f);
        }

         else if (h > 0 && !flipRight)
         {
            Flip();
        
        }

         


       
    }
    

    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Attack();
        Throw();
    }


 

    private void Jump() { 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("jump");
            _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 1 * jumpForce));
        }
}


    private void Attack()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
           animator.SetTrigger("attack");
           Collider2D[] hitEnemies =  Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayer);
           foreach(Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
            {
                enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }

        }
        
    }


    private void Throw()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {

            animator.SetTrigger("throw");
            GameObject newTrident = Instantiate(tridentPrefab, throwingPoint.position, tridentPrefab.transform.rotation);
            Rigidbody2D tridentRigidbody = newTrident.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            tridentRigidbody.AddForce(throwingPoint.up * throwForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            BoxCollider2D newBoxTrident = newTrident.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
            
            newBoxTrident.enabled = true;

        }
    }



    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (attackPoint == null) { return; }
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackPoint.position, attackRange);
    }


    private void Flip()
    {
        flipRight = !flipRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;      
        transform.localScale = theScale;
        tridentPrefab.transform.localScale = theScale;
    }



}
```